# firebase set/initialize values to zero dynamically

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm looking a good and right way to set/ initalize values with http trigger.
what I did is ref to the node in firebase and get data then update it.

```
module.exports.initializeAnswers = functions.https.onRequest(async(req,res)=>{
    try{
       // i want to initalize each key
        await firebase.ref('/CurrentGame').once('value',snapshot=>{
            snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot)=>{
                if(childSnapshot !=null){
                 childSnapshot.update(0)

                }
                return false
              });
        })
    }catch(e){
        console.info(e)
        return res.status(400).send({error:0})
    }
})
```

I'm looking for a right way and not by the 'update' function

[image]

I want to initalize each value to zero with http trigger

Comment: Note that a DataSnapshot is an "immutable copy of the data at a Database location" and "cannot be modified and will never change". See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.DataSnapshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you will have several children (variable number) under the "answers" node and only one "rightAnswer" node. If my understanding is correct, the following code will do the trick:

```
exports.initializeAnswers = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

    admin.database().ref('/CurrentGame/answers').once('value', snapshot => {

        const updates = {};
        snapshot.forEach((child) => {
            updates['/answers/' + child.key] = 0;
        });

        updates['/rightAnswer'] = 0;

        return admin.database().ref('/CurrentGame').update(updates);

    }).then(() => {
        res.status(200).end();
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).send(err);
    });

});
```

Comment: Note that I have edited my answer: I have reorganized the promise chaining in a more correct way

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Firebase Cloud Functions` to initialize the values on HTTP trigger. check [this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events)